# Write vector as the sum of w and w orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra, projection, gram-schmidt

Let $\mathbb{R}^3$ be given with the standard inner product and let $W$ be the subspace spanned by $\left(
\begin{array}{c}
4\\
-2\\
4\\
\end{array}
\right)$ and $\left(
\begin{array}{c}
-2\\
6\\
2\\
\end{array}
\right)$. Write the vector $\left(
\begin{array}{c}
20\\
10\\
-9\\
\end{array}
\right)$ as $w+w^{⊥}$ (orthogonal) with $w$ in $W$ and $w^{⊥}$ in $W^{⊥}$. I don't know how to solve this problem, I tried using the Gram-Schmidt method and orthogonal projection but I keep getting the wrong solution.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, we should find the bais of $W^{\bot}$.

If we assume $(x,y,z)^{t}\in W^{\bot}$, we have $\begin{cases}
 4x-2y+4z=0\\
 -2x+6y+2z=0\\
\end{cases}$.

Then $(-7,-4,5)^{t}$ is the basis of $W^{\bot}$.

We assume that $\left( \begin{array}{c}
 20\\
 10\\
 -9\\
\end{array} \right) =k_1\left( \begin{array}{c}
 4\\
 -2\\
 4\\
\end{array} \right) +k_2\left( \begin{array}{c}
 -2\\
 6\\
 2\\
\end{array} \right) +k_3\left( \begin{array}{c}
 -7\\
 -4\\
 5\\
\end{array} \right) $.

Solve this system of linear equations. We have $k_1=\dfrac{3}{4}$, $k_2=\dfrac{1}{4}$ and $k_3=\dfrac{-5}{2}$.

Finally, we get $\left( \begin{array}{c}
 20\\
 10\\
 -9\\
\end{array} \right) =\dfrac{3}{4}\left( \begin{array}{c}
 4\\
 -2\\
 4\\
\end{array} \right) +\dfrac{1}{4}\left( \begin{array}{c}
 -2\\
 6\\
 2\\
\end{array} \right) +\dfrac{-5}{2}\left( \begin{array}{c}
 -7\\
 -4\\
 5\\
\end{array} \right) $.